# How to connect Django running in a container with datadog agent running in host

Tags: networking, python, docker, django

I followed all the instructions in datadog but can't get it to work. Steps I have done so far:

I followed the instructions in [Tracing Docker Applications](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/docker/apm/?tab=java), and configured my Django with something like:

```python
DATADOG_TRACE = {
    'DEFAULT_SERVICE': 'my-app',
    'TAGS': {'env': 'production'},
    'AGENT_HOSTNAME': subprocess.check_output("/sbin/ip route | /usr/bin/awk '/default/ { print $3 }'", shell=True).strip(),
}
```

Note that I figured out a way to get the IP of the host from `ip route` command.

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:cannot send spans to 172.18.0.1:8126: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finally figured it out. Datadog agent is rejecting connections because it is only bound to localhost. I edited file `/etc/datadog-agent/datadog.yaml` and changed the following:

```yaml
use_dogstatsd: true
bind_host: 0.0.0.0
```

And now it works like a charm!